# Javascript no hace calculos al trabajar con @using (Html.BeginForm("", "", FormMethod.Post))

Tags: javascript, c#, html, jquery, mvc

Tengo una vista en la cuál dentro de ella agrego HTML y Javascript para hacer cálculos matemáticos, hasta ahí todo funciona bien, el problema surge a partir de que utilizo el @using (html.beginform...)... entonces este Javascript deja de funcionar, a lo que quiero llegar es que cuando coloco el HTML dentro del @using... deja de funcionar el Js.

Es decir, lo que me refiero es que el HTML fuera del @using los Js trabaja bien realizando los cálculos, pero cuando este mismo HTML está dentro del using los JS no hace los cálculos.

Espero pueda saber alguien el porqué y puedan ayudarme, dejo mi html adjunto:

```
     @*El Js con el Hmtl fuera del using trabaja bien, pero cuando el Htmk está dentro de del using el Js ya no hace los calculos*@

                @using (Html.BeginForm("InsertarRemuneracion", "Remuneracion", FormMethod.Post))
                {
                    <h5><strong>INGRESOS Y RETENCIONES DEL TRABAJADOR</strong></h5>
                    <input id="IdPersona2" name="Idpersona" hidden type="text" value="txtIdPersona" />
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-md-3">
                            Asignación Familiar
                            <select id="AsigFamiliar" name="AsigFamiliar" class="form-control AsigFamiliar" onchange="AsignacionFam(); Retenciones(); SueldoNeto(); SeguroSalud()">
                                <option selected disabled="disabled">Seleccione</option>
                                <option value="930">Si</option>
                                <option value="0">No</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-3">
                            Asignación Familiar S/.
                            <input id="AsigFam" name="txtAsigFam" class="form-control" placeholder="S/." disabled type="text" onkeyup="AsignacionFam()">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-3">
                            Otros S/.
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <input type="text" id="Otros" name="txtOtros" placeholder="S/." disabled class="form-control" onkeyup="IngresoBruto(); SueldoNeto()">
                                <span class="input-group-addon">
                                    <input type="checkbox" onclick="InhabilitaOtros(this); IngresoBruto(); SueldoNeto()">
                                </span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-3">
                            Ingreso Bruto S/.
                            <input id="IngresoB" name="txtRB" readonly class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="S/." onkeyup="Retenciones()">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-3">
                            Retención Obligatoria S/.
                            <input id="RetencionXAporte" name="txtAporteOblig" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="S/." readonly>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-3">
                            Ingreso Neto S/.
                            <input id="IngresoN" name="txtRN" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="S/." readonly>
                        </div>
                    </div><hr />
                    @*APORTACIONES DEL EMPLEADOR*@
                    <h5><strong>APORTACIONES DEL EMPLEADOR</strong></h5>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-md-3">
                            ESSalud S/.
                            <input id="ESSalud" name="txtEssalud" class="form-control" type="text" readonly placeholder="S/.">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-3">
                            SCTR
                            <select id="SeguroAdic" name="cboSCTR" class="form-control" onchange="SeguroSCTR(); AporteTotal()">
                                <option selected disabled="disabled">Seleccione</option>
                                <option value="1.25">Si</option>
                                <option value="0">No</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-3">
                            SCTR S/.
                            <input type="text" id="SCTR" name="txtSCTR" readonly placeholder="S/." class="form-control" onkeyup="SeguroSCTR()">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-3">
                            Aporte Total S/.
                            <input id="AporteEmpleador" name="txtAporteTotal" class="form-control" type="text" readonly placeholder="S/.">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-md-3">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Guardar</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                }
            </fieldset>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

@section scripts {

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function AsignacionFam() {
            caja = document.forms["sumar"].elements;
            var Asignacion = Number(caja["AsigFamiliar"].value);
            var PorcentajeAF = 0.10;
            var SueldoB = Number(caja["Sueldo"].value);

            Resultado = (Asignacion * PorcentajeAF);
            caja["AsigFam"].value = (Resultado);

            if (!isNaN(Resultado)) {
                var MontoTotal = Resultado + SueldoB;
                caja["IngresoB"].value = (MontoTotal);
            }
        }
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function InhabilitaOtros(chk) {

            obj = chk.form;
            if (chk.checked) {
                obj.Otros.disabled = false;
                obj.Otros.value = "";
                document.getElementById("Otros").focus();
            } else {
                obj.Otros.value = 0;
                obj.Otros.disabled = true;
            }
        }

        function IngresoBruto() {
            caja = document.forms["sumar"].elements;
            var Sueldo = Number(caja["Sueldo"].value);
            var Asignacion = Number(caja["AsigFam"].value);
            var Otros = Number(caja["Otros"].value);

            Resultado = (Sueldo + Asignacion + Otros);
            caja["IngresoB"].value = (Resultado);

            if (!isNaN(Resultado)) {
                var MontoTotal = Sueldo + Asignacion + Otros;
                caja["IngresoB"].value = (MontoTotal);
            }
        }

        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#Sueldo").append(function () {
                var value = $(this).val();
                $("#IngresoB").val(value);
            });
        });

        function Retenciones() {
            caja = document.forms["sumar"].elements;
            var Sueldo = Number(caja["Sueldo"].value);
            var Asignacion = Number(caja["AsigFam"].value);
            var AporteOb = 0.14;

            Resultado = (Sueldo + Asignacion) * AporteOb;
            caja["RetencionXAporte"].value = Math.round(Resultado);
        }

        function SueldoNeto() {
            caja = document.forms["sumar"].elements;
            var Sueldo = Number(caja["IngresoB"].value);
            var RetencionXAporte = Number(caja["RetencionXAporte"].value);

            Resultado = Sueldo - RetencionXAporte;
            caja["IngresoN"].value = Resultado;

            if (!isNaN(Resultado)) {
                var SueldoN = Sueldo - RetencionXAporte;;
                caja["IngresoN"].value = (SueldoN);
            }
        }
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function SeguroSalud() {
            caja = document.forms["sumar"].elements;

            var Sueldo = Number(caja["Sueldo"].value);
            var Asignacion = Number(caja["AsigFam"].value);
            var PorcentajeAF = 0.09;

            Resultado = (Sueldo + Asignacion) * PorcentajeAF;
            caja["ESSalud"].value = (Resultado);
        }
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function SeguroSCTR() {
            caja = document.forms["sumar"].elements;

            var Sueldo = Number(caja["Sueldo"].value);
            var Asignacion = Number(caja["AsigFam"].value);
            var Porcentaje = Number(caja["SeguroAdic"].value);
            var PorcentajeSCTR = Porcentaje / 100;

            Resultado = (Sueldo + Asignacion) * PorcentajeSCTR;
            caja["SCTR"].value = Math.round(Resultado);

            if (!isNaN(Resultado)) {
                var MontoTotal = (Resultado);
                caja["SCTR"].value = Math.round(MontoTotal);
            }
        }
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function AporteTotal() {
            caja = document.forms["sumar"].elements;

            var ESSalud = Number(caja["ESSalud"].value);
            var SCTR = Number(caja["SCTR"].value);

            Resultado = ESSalud + SCTR;
            caja["AporteEmpleador"].value = (Resultado);
        }
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#IdPersona1").append(function () {
                var value = $(this).val();
                $("#IdPersona2").val(value);
            });
        });
    </script>
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

es que tu form no se llama "sumar". Si quieres darle un id tiene que usar la sobrecarga que te permite añadir atributos HTML

```
Html.BeginForm("InsertarRemuneracion", "Remuneracion", FormMethod.Post, new {id="sumar", name="sumar"})
```

Comment: Gracias por las sugerencias, cambie todo el script nativo a Jquery y se soluciono todo, gracias.